# Mergesort in C output

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
void mergesort(int array[],int i,int j);
void merge(int a[],int i,int j);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
int array[] ={7,5,4,3,2,1};
mergesort(array,0,5);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ",array[i] );
}



return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


void mergesort(int array[],int i,int j)
{
int middle;
if (i == j)
    {
    return;
    }
else
    {
    middle = (i+j)/2;
    mergesort(array,i,middle);
    mergesort(array,middle+1,j);
    merge(array,i,j);
    }


} 

void merge(int array[],int i,int j)
{
int  b[100] = {0};
int forb =  0;
int INIi = i;
int middle = (i+j)/2;
int k = middle+1;
//MAKING TEMP ARRAY B
while((i<= middle) && (k <= j))
{
    if (array[i] <= array[k])
    {
        b[forb++] = array[i++]; 
    }
    else if(array[i] > array[k])
    {
        b[forb++] = array[k++];

    }
}
if (i>middle)
{
    for(;k<=j;)
    {
    b[forb++] = array[k++];
    }
}
else if (k>j)
{

for(;i<=middle;)
    {
    b[forb++] = array[i++];
    }
}
//COPYING BACK TO A
for(;INIi<= j;INIi++)

{
    array[INIi] = b[INIi]; 
}

}
```

The problem is I only get the half sorted array not full,I think the code is ok ,dont know whats going wrong.the merge function is placed correctly still the problem persists.
When i do with pen and paper the code should work but is not working.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger, line by line, to see what really happens.

Comment: This is a matter of debugging the code, and it's unlikely to help any future visitors.

Comment: can you please help,I dont know to use a debugger with C yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the merge code, you copy elements `i` to `j` of `array` into `b[0]` and upwards.

Then, in the copy back code, you copy from `b[INIi]` (appalling variable name, but that's tangential to the bug).  That only works accurately when `i` is 0; in general, `i` is not 0.

Assuming you have a C99 or C11 compiler (so you can define variables at arbitrary points in a function), then a fix is:

```
int n = 0;
for ( ; INIi <= j; INIi++)
    array[INIi] = b[n++];
```

---

Also, FYI, you can simplify the post-processing after the main merge loop from:

```
if (i>middle)
{
    for(;k<=j;)
    {
        b[forb++] = array[k++];
    }
}
else if (k>j)
{
    for(;i<=middle;)
    {
        b[forb++] = array[i++];
    }
}
```

to:

```
while (k <= j)
    b[forb++] = array[k++];
while (i <= middle)
    b[forb++] = array[i++];
```